# YouTube IFrame API stopping before end

Tags: youtube-api

Is it possible to stop a video using the YouTube API one second before the end or just stopping it resetting back to the beginning? This is regardless of the length of the video itself.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What does the YT API documentation say?

Comment: Not a lot. I can stop the video after so many seconds from the beginning but does not seem to have anything about stopping it from the end.

Comment: So you found the answer.

Comment: No. The video's are all different lengths so not so simple to say so many seconds from beginning hence why I need to be able to find a way of stopping the video one second from the end.

Comment: The answer is: *There is not answer.*

Comment: That's very helpful! One of the reasons why I do not use this site much.

Comment: As you indicated it looks like there's no way for it to be stopped/paused near the end. What I can suggest however, is to check the `onStateChanged` [event](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Events) and play it again when it ended (0)

Answer (score 1):

I disagree with the argument of NOT being able to stop a video before it ends. Specifically, in the API, you have access to:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference#Playback_status

```
Player.getCurrentTime();
Player.getDuration();
```

If you were to monitor the player object and compare these two, you could easily stop the video before it ends. An example would be (although probably not good in production):

```
setInterval(function() {
  var player = getPlayer(); //retrieve the player object

  if(player) {
   var duration = player.getDuration();
   var current  = player.getCurrentTime();


   if((duration - current) <= 1) {
     player.stopVideo();
   }
 }
}, 1000); //every second
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into an issue where for some reason the iframe player was stopping the video before the video's end, and so not triggering the `ENDED` event, and ran into this question while trying to find a solution for that. Since my approach can solve your problem as stated, here's what I did (I left the `console.log()` debug lines in to make it easier for someone else using this to play around with):

```
var player_timeout;
function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING) {
        console.log("PLAY [" + event.data + "]");
        timeout_set();
        }
    if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PAUSED) {
         console.log("PAUSED [" + event.data + "]");
        clearTimeout(player_timeout);
        }
    }
    
function timeout_func() {
    console.log("timeout_func");
    player.stopVideo(); // or whatever other thing you want to do 1 second before the end of the video
    }
    
function timeout_set() {
     console.log("timeout_set");
    var almostEnd_ms = (player.getDuration() - player.getCurrentTime() - 1) * 1000;
     console.log("almostEnd_ms: " + almostEnd_ms);
     console.log("player.getCurrentTime(): " + player.getCurrentTime());
    player_timeout = setTimeout(timeout_func, almostEnd_ms);
    }
```